# Is there any document for Tizen Web App Template? (like media controller, camera, pedometer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

When I create a new Tizen Wearable Web Project, Tizen IDE provides sample web apps like Camera, Media Controller, Pedometer. So, I created 'media controller template' for my project. But, it contains lot of js code. And I think that codes have something difference with usual javascript for webpage. So, I want to understand how it works, and how use jquery in this project either.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some research on developing Tizen Wearable apps - specifically go through the tutorials provided by Samsung which step through the foundations of Tizen Wearable development.

Tizen wearable apps are written in HTML5 (basically CSS, js and html), and the samples you are looking at reference the Tizen sdk. Just read through the [the documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-gear) and you will see that there are js calls to the Tizen apis which are most certainly not like 'usual javascrpt for webpage'.

Answer (score 0):

The "difference" you notice may also be because the js code in the samples are written using the [functional programming paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145053/javascript-as-a-functional-language).  This can be confusing for beginner programmers or programmers that are new to functional programming.

However, reading the documentation (IDE > Help > Help Content) will give a great idea of the various api's and how to call them. For example, there are some posts and sample code using "regular" javascript to implement similar functions in the samples ...

[denvycom.com/blog/accelerometer-data-in-javascript-in-your-gear-2/](http://denvycom.com/blog/accelerometer-data-in-javascript-in-your-gear-2/)

http://denvycom.com/blog/how-to-add-gestures-tap-swipe-to-your-gear-2-app/

-V.